# How to use i18n in a custom attribute on Aurelia?

Tags: typescript, localization, aurelia, i18next, custom-attribute

I have the following custom attribute in Aurelia:

```
import { fireEvent } from '_utils/events'
import { autoinject, customAttribute, inject } from 'aurelia-framework'
import $ from 'jquery'
import { I18N } from 'aurelia-i18n'
import 'Modernizr'
import 'pickadate/lib/compressed/picker'
import 'pickadate/lib/compressed/picker.date'

@customAttribute('datepicker')
@inject(Element)
@autoinject
export class DatePicker {
  // public i18N: I18N
  private usePickADate: boolean

  constructor (private element: Element, private i18n: I18N) {
    this.i18n = i18n
    this.usePickADate = !Modernizr.inputtypes.date
    $(this.element).pickadate({
      weekdaysShort: ['Ss', 'Mm', 'Tt', 'Ww', 'Th', 'Ff', 'Ss'],
      showMonthsShort: true,
      format: i18n.tr('general.date-format')
    })
  }

  public attached () {
    if (this.usePickADate) {
      $(this.element).pickadate()
        .on('change', (e: any) => {
          fireEvent(e.target, 'input')
        })
    }
  }

  public detached () {
    if (this.usePickADate) {
      $(this.element).pickadate('picker')
        .off('change')
        .stop()
    }
  }
}
```

Here I cannot use i18n to translate and localize. I get this error:

> Inner Error: Message: Cannot read property 'tr' of undefined

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject dependencies in two ways in Aurelia, either by using `@autoinject()` or by using `@inject()`.

- `@autoinject()` automatically looks at any constructor argument and automatically inject any dependency that you have imported.
- `@inject()` requires you to specifically mention any dependency you wish to inject into your class.

A simple case using `@autoinject()` would be:

```
import { I18N } from "aurelia-i18n";
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";

@autoinject()
export class DatePicker {

  constructor (private element: Element, private i18n: I18N) { }

}
```

If you do wish to use `@inject()` over `@autoinject()` for any reason at all, be sure to inject all dependencies, like so:

```
import { I18N } from "aurelia-i18n";
import { inject } from "aurelia-framework";

@inject(Element, I18N)
export class DatePicker {

  constructor (private element: Element, private i18n: I18N) { }

}
```

You're using both in your question, which seems to mess things up.

Comment: Thank you soooo much. It is perfect. unfortunately after I set the datePicker up , binding does not work. I see the new date in input but it does not bind to "currentDate" in View Model. Do you have any solution for this problem. I use datePicker in model with this code: <input datepicker type="date" id="date" value.two-way="currentDate">

Comment: I'd need a little more code, maybe ask a new question if you can't find the problem yourself, but try to find the answer yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I deleted `@inject(Element)`:

```
import { autoinject, customAttribute } from 'aurelia-framework'
....
@customAttribute('datepicker')
@autoinject
export class DatePicker {
....
```

Comment: If you do need to use `inject` over `autoinject`, remember to add all your dependencies in the `inject()` decorator.

Comment: How can I do it? I want to inject Element. Could you please give me an example code